# Calculate how long a key is pressed in a keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard

is it possible to have to use two keys for example and it will accumulate the time pressed for each key, for example key LEFT and RIGHT, so every time you click on one of them it will accumulate the time it has been pressed for, in case you press the same key again, it will add the time so at the end you get total time pressed for each key.

How can this be done?

Comment: In what language? It's hard to answer this kind of question with no indication on the language or environnement you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends quite a bit on the platform.  But event-driven platforms have it kinda easy, if they treat key-down and key-up as events (most do, including .net, java, and Windows).

Just listen for the key-down event, and record the time it happened.  When you get a key-up event for that same key, just subtract the time it happened from the time you recorded.  The difference between the two will be the duration of that keypress.

Catch is, depending on how your platform handles key repeat, you may get multiple key-downs for the same key before you get a key-up.  Only keep track of the first (since the last key-up or app start, of course) for each key.  And since you can press more than one key at a time, if you want to do this right, you'll be able to remember the key-down time for multiple keys.

If you want to keep track of the total time, then take that time difference you found on key-up, and add it to a running total for that key.

In JS:

```
(function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output'),
        totalTime = {},
        pressed = {};

    window.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.which in pressed) return;
        pressed[e.which] = e.timeStamp;
    };

    window.onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (!(e.which in pressed)) return;
        var duration = ( e.timeStamp - pressed[e.which] ) / 1000;
        if (!(e.which in totalTime)) totalTime[e.which] = 0;
        totalTime[e.which] += duration;
        output.innerHTML +=
            '<p>Key ' + e.which + ' was pressed for ' +
            duration + ' seconds this time' +
            '(' + totalTime[e.which] + ' total)</p>';
        delete pressed[e.which];
    };
})();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, could you please have a look at this, its the only one I found in this website, so it should be on the same concept apart from that I want to get a accumulated and total time for each key pressed, so you must see the time accumulating when pressing the same key, for instance key 37 shows total time of how long it has been pressed. Please help  http://jsfiddle.net/EeXVX/

Comment: Just take `duration` and add it to a running total for that key.  Like `totalTime[e.which] += duration;`.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste it for me, much appreciated                                           var output = document.getElementById('output'),
    pressed = {};

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if ( pressed[e.which] ) return;
    pressed[e.which] = e.timeStamp;
};
    
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if ( !pressed[e.which] ) return;
    var duration = ( e.timeStamp - pressed[e.which] ) / 1000;
    output.innerHTML += '<p>Key ' + e.which  + ' was pressed for ' + duration + ' seconds</p>';
    pressed[e.which] = 0;
};

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate that. if anyone could make it a bit better and have only one line showing for one key so its neater, rather than showing a list of the same key